# How to avoid distortion (quantization error) in DDS output in STM32?

Tags: dds, quantization

I have been using a timer interrupt to generate sine waves with an STM32, however, for higher phase increments (to get higher frequencies as output), there are quantization errors (distortions).

To solve this problem, I thought of using half period sine LUT so that the resolution would increase. I have a hard time implementing it in code. Could anyone help me with this?

```
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "math.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define PI 3.14159
#define NS 4096
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */
/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
DAC_HandleTypeDef hdac1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim16;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

uint32_t Fs = 100000;
uint64_t f_exp = 10000; //
uint64_t tuning = 429496729;
//429496729
uint64_t idx = 0;
int bit_depth = 4095;
int output_val = 0;
uint64_t phase = 0;
int LUT[NS];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void);
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* LUT */
//
void sine_val(){
    for(int i = 0;i < NS;i++){
        LUT[i] = (sin(i*2* PI/NS)+1)*(bit_depth/2);
    }
}

void phase_increment(int16_t freq_out, uint32_t Fs, uint8_t acc_depth) {
    tuning = (round(freq_out * pow(2, acc_depth) /  Fs));
}

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM16_Init();
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  sine_val();
//  phase_increment(f_exp, Fs, 32);
  HAL_DAC_Start(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1);
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim16);



  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief DAC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 0 */

  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 1 */

  /** DAC Initialization
  */
  hdac1.Instance = DAC1;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** DAC channel OUT1 config
  */
  sConfig.DAC_SampleAndHold = DAC_SAMPLEANDHOLD_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_NONE;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_ConnectOnChipPeripheral = DAC_CHIPCONNECT_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_UserTrimming = DAC_TRIMMING_FACTORY;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac1, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM16 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM16_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 1 */
  htim16.Instance = TIM16;
  htim16.Init.Prescaler = 10-1;
  htim16.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim16.Init.Period = 64-1;
  htim16.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim16.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim16.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM16_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM16_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart2, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_GREEN_GPIO_Port, LED_GREEN_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED_GREEN_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED_GREEN_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED_GREEN_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

  // Check which version of the timer triggered this callback and toggle LED
  if (htim == &htim16 )
  {
      //to generate sine wave
//       HAL_DAC_Start(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1);
//    //need to update the phase increment
//    // Update the phase accumulator value by adding the phase increment value
//

         phase += tuning;
         idx = (tuning >> 20) & 0xFFF;
         output_val = LUT[idx];
//
//
//       HAL_DAC_SetValue(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R, output_val);
////      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5);



}
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

I assume we have to use the interrupt (in section 'user code begin 4') to invert the LUT for the second half of the sine wave. However, I couldn't solve it despite trying to use some logic. I'd appreciate it anyone could help me with this.

Edit: [image: output]

Comment: These are *not* quantization errors; the quantization of the numbers in your table is always the same.

Comment: To get a somewhat constant amplitude sine at the output of the reconstruction filter with few samples per period while varying frequency, be sure to output one sample at each peak and change the timer interval. There is little difference between 2 and 4 uniform interval samples per period. To get helpful answers, describe what artefact in the output exactly you want to get rid of.

Comment: I uploaded the output of my waveform. Since the limit of my DAC resolution and RAM size are 12 bits, i cannot go further for which i decided to use half/quarter period of my LUT. My sample rate is 100k and if i go further, the output is not exactly as calculated. 
https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/Technical-Tutorial-DDS/Section4.pdf based on this, i assume this is due to quantization error which is constraining me from having a pure sine wave. At lower frequencies, it's much smoother.